# Javascript - String to multi-layered array

Tags: javascript, arrays

**My function gets a string from a webservice, which represents a multi layered array structure. I then assign it to a variable. Something like this:**

```
//incoming = [ [1,2,3], ['a','b','c'], [{v:1437, f:'1437 - Point A'}, {v:1440, f:'1440 -  Point B'}, {v:1445, f:'1445 -  Point C'}], [6.7,8.2,9.2] ]  -- this is the incoming string
   arrays =  incoming;
```

When I try to pass this to another function, javascript always warns me that this is a string, not an array (which the function requires to split it up later to get the smaller arrays).

So far I tried this:

```
var globalArray = [];

$.each(arrays, function(key, object) {
    var innerArray = [];
    innerArray=object;
    globalArray.push(innerArray);
});
```

But then the globalArray will not contain multiple arrays, but a lot of strings which will become siblings.

```
[ 1,2,3,a,b,c,{v:1437, f:'1437 - Point A'}, {v:1440, f:'1440 -  Point B'}, {v:1445, f:'1445 -  Point C'},6.7,8.2,9.2 ]
```

**How could I recreate the array structure based on the content of the string?**

Comment: please add the string, you get.

Comment: what is "`a`" in the array string?

Comment: why not change the input at the webservice to a valid [JSON](http://json.org/) string?

Comment: Can you please show me how it would look like? Whenever I used JSON, I had names before the actual values as keys, so I could decompress. In a case like this I am bit unfamiliar of it's technique, how can I decompress it to an array which has the inner arrays in it.

Comment: assuming a right formated array, a JSON string looks like `'[[1,2,3],["a","b","c"],["e","f","g"],[6.7,8.2,9.2]]'` for it.

Comment: So which is the best way to decompress it to become an actual array with inner arrays? The content of the incoming string is always changing.

Comment: it would be easier, if the string would be a valid array/object literal (with comma separated arrays/objects).

Comment: Ok that's something I can work it out. I've edited the incoming string.

Comment: now you need to use double quotes inside and quote the keys of the objects as well with double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a JSON string

```
[[1,2,3],["a","b","c"],[{"v":1437,"f":"1437 - Point A"},{"v":1440,"f":"1440 - Point B"},{"v":1445,"f":"1445 - Point C"}],[6.7,8.2,9.2]]
```

as defined by the [standard](http://json.org/) and parse it with [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) for getting an object.

```js
var json = '[[1,2,3],["a","b","c"],[{"v":1437,"f":"1437 - Point A"},{"v":1440,"f":"1440 - Point B"},{"v":1445,"f":"1445 - Point C"}],[6.7,8.2,9.2]]',
    object = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you Nina for the detailed answer and example!

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1** - Output valid JSON from your endpoint, something like this:

```
[ 
  [1,2,3], 
  ["a","b","c"],
  [
    {"v":1437, "f":"1437 - Point A"}, 
    {"v":1440, "f":"1440 -  Point B"}, 
    {"v":1445, "f":"1445 -  Point C"}
  ],
  [6.7,8.2,9.2] 
]
```

**Step 2** - Parse the input with `JSON.parse()`

Not sure what's going on with the service, but literally every language has multiple decent JSON encoder/parser. Please use them. Never try to manually serialize your data especially if it's almost json.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! As suggested, I made sure to use a JSON instead of a String. I wish I could accept two answers at the same time. Thank you again!